# android some issue with viewpagerindicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement  `viewpagerindicator`   within my app.

I am using viewpagerindicator lib. and my code is bellow link.

http://pastebin.com/TRUazPmb

I am getting an error,

```
11-15 13:07:35.145: E/AndroidRuntime(431): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager adapter must implement TitleProvider to be used with TitlePageIndicator.
```

at `ViewPageActivity`s line   `indicator.setViewPager(mPager);`

Anybody help me how to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ViewPageFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
```

replace this line with

```
public class ViewPageFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider{
```

You have to implement TitleProvider for your pager adapter if you are using titlePageindicator.
you might need to add some functions after implementing this...

to call different children..

```
@Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            if (arg0 == 0) {
                return new Fragment1();
            } else if (arg0 == 1) {
                return new Fragment2();
            } else if (arg0 == 2){
                return new Fragment3();
            } else {
                return new Fragment0();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank u, its working.  One more thing i want to know  body part is a text so that i can easily gave that. i want to put different activity for different titles, how can i do that?

Comment: i want to put different different views for different viewpage, is it possible?

Comment: yes possible, you need to check for child index requested, if it matches with that of yours, you supply the fragment that you think is apt at that index.

Comment: can u tell me where i will check the child index?

Comment: in your pager adapter, you have getItem(int position) , position is the child index.

Comment: ya that i know where i ll use that index. In page adapter or in pageFragment?

Comment: can we take this conversation to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5008/discussion-between-yashwanth-kumar-and-jyosna)

Comment: bcz in ViewPageFragment class onCreateView is an override method, here only i have to check for index, how can i check in this override method?

Comment: come to chat i have little doudt

Comment: will u come to chat? i have some doubt to ask

Comment: +1 for nice answer ..Hello i have use Gallery and  viewpagerindicator .On Gallery's every image click event i want to add different Adapter class .is this possible?

Comment: @YashwanthKumar I'm getting `TitleProvider cannot be resolved to a type` error. Which package I need to import to avoid this?